# android hilt Inject into ViewModel

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

i am try to inject a module to MyViewModel

here is my Module

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object EngineModule {
    @Provides
    fun getEngine(): String = "F35 Engine"
}
```

and this my viewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel() {
    @Inject lateinit var getEngine: String

    fun getEngineNameFromViewModel(): String = getEngineName()
}
```

and it throws

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property getEngine
> has not been initialized

however if i change `ViewModelComponent::class` to `ActivityComponent::class` and inject like this

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var getEngine: String
```

it works perfectly

any idea how to inject viewModels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can just remove `@Inject constructor` since you are already providing the dependency using dagger module:

```
@HiltViewModel 
class MyViewModel (private val engineName: String): ViewModel() {

    fun getEngineNameFromViewModel(): String = engineName

}
```

So, Basically you can either provide the dependency using dagger module or constructor injection.

Answer (score 1):

Since required dependency is going to be injected in the `ViewModel`'s constructor, you just need to modify your code in the following way to make it work:

```
@HiltViewModel 
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(private val engineName: String): ViewModel() {

    fun getEngineNameFromViewModel(): String = engineName

}
```

Comment: thanks for responding , it throws `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.hilttest.viewModel.MyViewModel` , i guess because im using viewModel in my Composable Screen like this
`@Composable
fun ScreenOne(myViewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel())`
without using factory

Comment: That's another problem, no what you were asking for... Different problem, different question, or just edit these one adding the full picture of the problem.